# Facebook wall post using php oauth error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

Here is my code for FACEBOOK wall post using oauth,

```
<?php
class Facebook
{
    /**
     * @var The page id to edit
     */
    private $page_id = '559515220745012';

    /**
     * @var the page access token given to the application above
     */
    private $page_access_token = 'CAAFxzhxYP6kBAJZADenicftONfBf10ZBAv6uziZAUz4ZAlyOzIpkYZBtnonqarkih7TyT3N7kS3S6APvS80MWJRGjxgCGHjoZAapTZCqnJf8ltymJK27D8eG57cFqNQZBsCIu6xKdjXjHZBZCXQgB8hT0pIMfLoiHYJo7t9ZAXAZAVru7QZDZD';

    /**
     * @var The back-end service for page's wall
     */
    private $post_url = '';

    /**
     * Constructor, sets the url's
     */
    public function Facebook()
    {
        $this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed';
    }

    /**
     * Manages the POST message to post an update on a page wall
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return string the back-end response
     * @private
     */
    public function message($data)
    {
        // need token
        $data['access_token'] = $this->page_access_token;

        // init
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // execute and close
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // end
        return $return;
    }
}

$facebook = new Facebook();

$facebook->message(array( 'message'  => 'The status header',
                          'link'        => 'http://theurltopoint.to',
                          'picture'  => 'http://thepicturetoinclude.jpg',
                          'name'        => 'Name of the picture, shown just above it',
                          'description' => 'Full description explaining whether the header or the picture') );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($facebook->message());
echo "</pre>";                        

?>
```

I got an error like this `{"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing message or attachment","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}`

And also the post is not post into the wall. Help me to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Do not public your access tokens. People can spam using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed this line:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
...
```

Comment: Comment `print_r($facebook->message());` Just call the message function once, its working fine i checked

Comment: I tried also that. Still the same. The message is not shown in the Facebook wall

Comment: Can you pls try once again, the following code is working: [code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ClPPNOzh5TSIUeyJgN_yaHRw0vQcuTLlyh3NLWXQQ5M/edit?usp=sharing) . Replace `PAGE_ID` and `TOKEN`

Comment: The code is working fine now. But the wall post has been shown under my account. I want to show the post in My fan page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35287/discussion-between-shivaji-and-shadowfax)

Comment: Can you help me to fix the above code. I want the above code with out class.